# Submit formset data using class based views

Tags: python, django

I am creating a formset with django which contains children information. I am using createview (CBV) for this. The form is displayed properly, it has functionality of adding children and removing children all working properly. But, when I click on submit, `form_invalid` is called instead of `form_valid`. To know this issue I printed `form.errors` and i saw following errors

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>deal_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>child_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>son_or_daugher<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>child_age<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>child_education<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>child_occupation<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Below is my code

Template :-

```
{% extends "forms_app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table">
                {{ childrens.management_form }}

                {% for form in childrens.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <a href="">back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'forms_app/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
            addText: 'Add Children',
            deleteText: 'Remove',
            prefix: 'familymember_set'
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

View Code

```
class ChildrenView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'forms_app/children_form.html'
    form_class = ChildrenForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forms_app:deal-entering')

    # fields = ['name','class']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ChildrenView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            print('child form initial data')
            initial_list = []
            try:
                print('its going on')
                for i in range(self.request.session['children_count']   ):
                    print('still going on')
                    for field in self.fields:
                        initial_list.append(self.request.session[i + field])
                        data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet(initial = initial_list)
            except:
                data['childrens'] = ChildrenFormSet()
            # data['childrens'].extra = self.request.session['children_count']
        return data


    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            count = 0
            for f in form:
                for field in ['deal_id','child_name','son_or_daugher','child_age','child_education','child_occupation']:
                    self.request.session[count + field] = f.cleaned_data[field]
                count += 1

            self.request.session['children_count'] = count

            for i in range(count):
                for field in ['deal_id','child_name','son_or_daugher','child_age','child_education','child_occupation']:
                    print(self.request.session[i + field])


            for field in self.fields:
                self.request.session[field] = form.cleaned_data[field]

            self.request.session['valid_children'] = True

        return super(ChildrenView, self).form_valid(form)


    def form_invalid(self,form):

        if form.is_valid():
            pass
        print(form.errors)
        print('form invalid')
        return super(ChildrenView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Form Code

```
class ChildrenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Children
        fields = '__all__'


    def clean(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)

ChildrenFormSet = modelformset_factory(Children,fields = '__all__',extra=1)
```

I have read several post on StackOverflow. I went through django documents but still I am unable to figure out the problem. Please help me.

Below is screenshot of my form
[image]

In case you have any problem understanding please comment, I will reply superfast.

Comment: Does the error appear when you fill every field with data or only if the form is blank?

Comment: Your `form_valid` is trying to validate `ChildrenForm` which is the `form_class` and isn't in your template.  I normally use `formsets` linking them to a parent form (so the parent form goes in the `form_class`) and I'm not sure how you use CBV without that.  Are these children related to a parent in someway?  If so, set `form_class=parentForm` and in your template put `{{ form.as_p }}` straight after the `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: This error comes when i submit the form @SallyZeitler. Form is completely filled

Comment: @HenryM there is no parent. This form contain only children. How to add parentForm

Comment: This may seem like an unusual suggestion, but have you tried re-writing the view as a functional based view? Personally, I find working with formsets in a functional based view easier to debug.

Comment: Nope, i changed my way. Unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in this line:

```py
form_class = ChildrenForm
```

Try removing that line or change it to:

```
form_class = ChildrenFormSet
```

I think that your `form_valid` is checking against the form ChildrenForm.

Comment: After changing giving new error. Now form is not loading :- __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Indeed this is the issue, however it will not work with `CreateView`. I would approach it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57561086/2996101).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to completely ignore `form_valid` because you don't have a ChildrenForm to be valid so override the `post` method instead

Try something like this:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    formset = ChildrenFormSet(self.request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
       do stuff
    else :
       return self.form.is_invlaid()
    return redirect to your success url
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template, renders `ChildrenFormSet` instead of the `ChildrenForm`.

Consequently, the user enters the data in the formset while `ChildrenView` is validating the `ChildrenForm` which is inevitably empty.

[@HenryM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560867/2996101) provides a logical solution (I have not tested it) but it cancels the meaning of using a `CreateView`.

I would use a `FormView` in order to manipulate the Formset directly:

forms.py:

```
class ChildrenView(FormView):
    template_name = 'forms_app/children_form.html'
    form_class = ChildrenFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forms_app:deal-entering')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the formset is valid, create the objects in the database
        """
        instances = []
        for sub_form in form:
            obj = Children(**sub_form.cleaned_data)
            instances.append(obj)
        Children.objects.bulk_create(instances)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Here you define the queryset that gathers the forms presented to the user.
        We return none() in order to have always an empty formset and simplify the code.
        """
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["queryset"] = Children.objects.none()
        return kwargs
```

children_form.html:

```
{% extends "forms_app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_table }}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <a href="">back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'forms_app/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
            addText: 'Add Children',
            deleteText: 'Remove',
            prefix: 'familymember_set'
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```